# p5.js leaflet custom markers do not appear

Tags: javascript, leaflet, p5.js

I am using p5.js and leaflet to create maps with custom markers, as explained here in the [documentation](https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/)

Unfortunately, whereas the default markers do show on the map, the custom markers do not appear. I tried all kinds of variations as mentioned on stackoverflow and other websites, but no matter what I do, I cannot get it to work.

Here is my code (all the files, including the svg are located in the same folder)

index.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>p5.js example</title>
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #1b1b1b;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libraries/MovingMarker.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="../addons/p5.sound.js"></script> -->
  <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css"
     integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY="
     crossorigin=""/>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js"
     integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo="
     crossorigin=""></script>
  <style>
    #map { height: 640px; }
  </style>
  <div id="map"></div>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

sketch.js

```
var map;
var lat = 51.508;
var lon = -0.11;
var newLatLng;
var marker = null;

var myIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'triangle.svg',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76]
});

function setup() {

 map = L.map('map').setView([lat, lon], 5);
 
 L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
     maxZoom: 19,
     attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
 }).addTo(map);  

}

function draw() {
 
 // create marker
 marker = L.marker([lat, lon], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(map);

}
```